# parse list to a data frame with list element names corresponding to data frame cell location

Tags: r

I have a list output from `xlsx` package with some spreadsheet values.  The list element names are the cells locations in format "row.column".  I need to convert it back to a data frame.  I have a solution that is very slow.  I would appreciate any ideas on how to improve the code.

```
library(stringr)

#create toy list example. list element name corresonds to data frame cell location.
cols<-40
rows <- 20
cells <- paste(rep(1:rows,each=cols),rep(seq(1:cols),rows),sep=".")
cells <- sample(cells,length(cells),replace = F)
set.seed(42)
toy.l <- sapply(cells,function(x) rnorm(1,2,1))
names(toy.l) <- cells

# convert list to data frame
parse_list <- function(l) {
  col.count <- max(unlist(lapply(1:length(l),function(x) {as.numeric(str_extract(names(l[x]),"(?<=\\.)\\d+"))})))
  df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA_character_ , 20*col.count),ncol=col.count),stringsAsFactors = F)
  for (i in 1:length(l)) {
    df[as.numeric(str_extract(names(l[i]),"\\d+(?=\\.)")),as.numeric(str_extract(names(l[i]),"(?<=\\.)\\d+"))] <- l[[i]]
  }
  return(df)
}
df.soln <- parse_list(toy.l)
```

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to do with parse_list?

Comment: `parse_list` takes a list with elements like, `l$'2.3'` and places the element value in a dataframe cell [2,3].  change the cols and rows to small numbers and look at `toy.l` and `df.soln`  structures.  I think it will make sense